# The distinction between real and virtual particles

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions, propagator, virtual-particles

I will take the simple case of a spin-0 field:

$$W(J)=-\iint d^4xd^4y J(x)D(x-y)J(y)$$

which in the Fourier transform becomes:

$$W(J) = -\int d^4 p J(p)^* \frac{1}{p^2-m^2+i\epsilon} J(p)$$

what I know is that a real particle satisfies $p^2 = m^2$.

But we are integrating over all values of $p$, right? What does a real particle mean in that sense? When the integral is summing up the different values, it adds terms which are real particles, while others are not. What does this mean?

Comment: What do you think the $W(J)$ you've written down here has to do with particles (either real or virtual)? What *exactly* is the question here?

Comment: This $W(J)$ is, up to factors, just the generating functional of connected time-ordered correlation functions in a free scalar theory. In that case, at this stage, it is just an object which we differentiate to get correlation functions. I know that when people draw Feynman diagrams they often talk about particles, but the truth is that those diagrams are just pictorial representations of a terms in a perturbative expansion of said correlation functions. Actual particles only come in when we subject those correlators to the LSZ prescription and relate to scattering amplitudes.